# Update state of array variable

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the state of setArray but I cant change it. The console.log shows empty array. The other states are working but not this
I've used useEffect too but nothing is happening. Kindly give me a solution.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import {useEffect} from 'react';

const Register = () =>{

   const classes = useStyle();
   const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
   const [array, setArray] = React.useState([])



   const submit = (event) =>{
       const obj = {}
       event.preventDefault();
       if(array.length === 0){
          localStorage.setItem('name', name);
          localStorage.setItem('password',password);
          localStorage.setItem('array',JSON.stringify(array))
          obj.id = Math.random();
          obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
          obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
          setArray(array => [...array,obj])
          console.log(array);
          return alert('You are registered'); 
       }
    }

 return(
    <div>
        <div className = {classes.formWrapper}>
            <Paper elevation={3} className = {classes.paper} >
            <Typography variant="h5" style = {{ textAlign : 'center'}}>Register</Typography>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField id="username" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {name} name = "username"  label="Username" onChange = {e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <TextField id="password" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {password} name = "password"  label="Password" onChange = {e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Link to='/'>SignIn</Link>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {{width : '100%'}} onClick = {submit} >Register </Button>
            </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: You are trying to access the state through console.log( ), just after calling setState( ) . The setState is asynchronus in nature and thus it would give you previous or initialState ,if you to try to print it in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is asynchronous. It means you can’t call it on one line and assume the state has changed on the next.

From React Docs.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Comment: *Awaiting* a function that has `void` as it's return type makes absolutely no sense. Also it's irrelevant that the state update might or might not be asynchronous. The described problem is simply a case of a *stale closure*.

Comment: Can you elaborate this with an answer?
By looking at the description of the question,it is clear that OP is concerned about the inability to log the state,just after mutating it with setState( ). 
In React docs it is clearly mentioned why it happens and there is a github thread too.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527

Additionally,I tried to give a small code example to achieve what he want to.
Thanks.

Comment: I've posted my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you are adamant to log the state after the setState,then try this(just to experiment,dont do in prod app):
```js
async logAftersetState(){
    await setState(array => [...array,obj]);
    console.log(array);
}

// Call logAfterSetState() inside your submit function

```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the reason why `console.log(array);` logs the *old* array is **not** because `setArray` (or rather, it's implementation) is or is not asynchronous. It is because, simply put, it's **impossible**.
And even if it were fully synchronous, it would still be so.

---

The reason:

1. Javascript is a [*pass-by-value*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034) (or rather *call-by-sharing*), or more importantly **not a** *pass-by-reference* language. This means, that there is absolutely no way to implement `setArray` in such a way that it could change what is assigned to `array`. A dead giveaway that you shouldn't even assume this was possible, is that `array` is a `const`.
2. Except from throwing an exception, it is impossible to prevent the execution of the remaining code **after** `setArray(array => [...array,obj])` from **inside** `setArray`.

Also note, that this is not a *react thing*. It's simply a part of the language as is. So there's also no way to *fix* this (not that I'm saying a fix is needed).

---

So what is really happening? Quit simple:

`const submit = (event) => { ... }` forms a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102) over the constant `array`. And thus `console.log(array);` must refer to that value. That `setArray(array => [...array,obj])` *stages* a state update for the *next render*, and whether that process is synchronous or asynchronous, is completely irrelevant here.

---

So how to refer to a *changed* state variable?

1. use `useEffect` appropriately.
2. use the value you would want to assign as the new state where you calcualte it. E.g.:

   ```
   setArray(array => {
       const next = [...array, obj];

       console.log(next); // new value

       return next;
   });

   console.log(array); // *still* the old value, for the above mentioned reasons
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this writeup. I hope OP accepts this as 'accepted answer'

Comment: @PiyushMahapatra You're welcome! Please share the knowledge! This type of question get's asked so much, and falsely answered so often...